# Qt Installer Framework controller function not getting called

Tags: qt, qt5, qt-installer

I would like to modify the flow of my QtIFW(3.0) installer using a controller function, it seems trivial to do, however I can't seem to find a good example of where the function / script should reside and how to make the installer aware of it.

Things I have tried without success:

- Putting a controller function into my component script
- Creating *controller.qs* file with the function in my packages root directory
- Including the *controller.qs* script file in my package.xml configuration

My controller script (*controller.qs*) is just boilerplate at the moment:

```
function Controller() {
    console.log("Controller()");
}
```

During installer runtime the installer executes as expected except the controller function is never called..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [Qt IFW reference](https://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/ifw-globalconfig.html), you just have to add your controller script in the configuration XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Installer>
    <!-- Your config -->
    <ControlScript>controller.qs</ControlScript>
</Installer>
```

Not that there is only 1 control script per installer, not per component!

Comment: Just missed it.  Thanks a lot.